# Xamarin Android VideoView Resize Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, android-videoview

In our Xamarin Android (Android Pie 9.0) application we display a Video Stream (RTSP) in a quarter screen configuration using a VideoView. The VideoView is embedded inside a RelativeLayout and a FrameLayout that all define layout_width and layout_height to "match_parent".

When the user touchs the video we magnify the VideoView in order to display it in a full screen.

All the configurations work :

- Bottom Left Quarter Screen
- Top Right Quarter Screen
- Bottom Right Quarter Screen

except one : **Top Left Quarter Screen**. The video has the same size (quarter screen size) in the full screen and is not magnified.

In order to exclude a Layout issue i tried the same code with an **ImageView** instead of the VideoView and **it works fine for the 4 quarter screen configurations**.

The VideoView resize is done using the FrameLayout

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout1);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = frameLayout.LayoutParameters as FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
layoutParams.LeftMargin = 0;
layoutParams.TopMargin = 0;
layoutParams.Width = fullScreenWidth;
layoutParams.Height = fullScreenHeight;
frameLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
```

I have been able to reproduce the issue in a simple Xamarin Form Sample app with this axml : "contenet_main.axml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <!--<ImageView android:id="@+id/demoImageView" android:src="@drawable/image" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>-->
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/demoVideoView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This axml file is included in the activity_main.axml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</FrameLayout>
```

For the failing TopLeft case it is the only case where the LeftMargin and TopMargin are not changed when we magnify the videoView because only the Width and Height are changed.

I tried to change the layoutParams.LeftMargin or layoutParams.TopMargin from 0 to 1 in order to check whether **it was a "dirty" problem and with this trick it works.** But is not acceptable.

Hence i tried all the recommended solutions to force a layout redraw that i found in stackOverflow but no way the TopLeft Quarter screen case does not work :

- ForceInvalidate
- Invalidate + RequestLayout

I also searched whether a related bug was referenced but i did not found any entry.

Thanks.

Comment: You could post the full code in xml , which will be helpful to find out the cause .

Comment: I added the axml

Comment: To set the videoView to full screen, try using the `LayoutParameters` class to define the layout. Check the code `VideoView videoView = FindViewById<VideoView>(Resource.Id.videoView);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.WindowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);
var _params = (Android.Widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams)videoView.LayoutParameters;
_params.Width = metrics.WidthPixels;
_params.Height = metrics.HeightPixels;
_params.LeftMargin = 0;
videoView.LayoutParameters = _params;`